# 右クリックメニューからVimを開く方法

Tags: linux, vim

現在Linux Mint 18.3を使っています。

テキストファイルを右クリックしたとき、「Vimで開く」というメニューがあるのですが、
それをクリックしても何も起こりません。

どうすれば右クリックからVimを起動できるようになるのでしょうか？

- Vimは確かapt installでインストールしたと思います。
- デスクトップ環境はMATEです。
- ファイルマネージャー上での右クリックです。
- 端末上で「vim ファイル名」で右クリックで開けないファイルも開けます。

Comment: Vim はどのようにインストールなさいましたか？

Comment: ①Vimは確かapt installでインストールしたと思います。②デスクトップ環境はMATEです。③ファイルマネージャー上での右クリックです。④端末上で「vim ファイル名」で右クリックで開けないファイルも開けます。

Comment: MATE はよく知りませんが一般論としてはコマンドラインで `gtk-launch vim 対象ファイル` で開ければ、GUI でもうまくいく気がします。このコマンドでエラーが出ますか？ また、`xdg-open /usr/share/applications/vim.desktop` で vim が起動しますでしょうか？ 回避策としては、好みでは無いのかも知れませんが gvim（vim-gtk や vim-gtk3）を入れてみる、という手もあるかと思います。

Comment: 'gtk-launch vim 対象ファイル'でエラーが発生しました。そのエラーをもとにxtermをインストールしたところ起動できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

結論としては、　パッケージxtermをインストールすることで起動するようになりました。

コメントを頂いたように`gtk-launch vim 対象ファイル`と打ったところ、
`xtermを子プロセスとして起動できませんでした。そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません。`
のようなエラーが出たため、試しにxtermをインストールしたところ起動するようになりました。

これが正当なやり方なのかはわかりませんが、参考まで。